# GitHub Enterprise Administrator Code Review & Merge

Tags: git, github

I am new to git enterprise.
In my enterprise account I have created a team named "Developer". I have given **write** access to it because if I give ***read*** or ***triage*** access they cannot push their branch in our private repository.
Then I have created branch protection rule having pattern "main" and enabled following factors:

```
1. Require a pull request before merging - enabled
    - [ a ] Require approvals - enabled
    - [ b ] Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed - enabled
    - [ c ] Require review from code owners - enabled

2. Require status checks to pass before merging - enabled
    - [ a ] Require branches to be up to date before merging - enabled
```

The issue is anyone from developer team can approve and merge the pull request.

Developer team should only be able to do following:

1. Clone repo.
2. Create branch and push modifications into their respective branches.
3. Create pull request.

Administrator can then approve and merge/ reject.
What configuration changes should I do?

Comment: the developer should `fork` the repository and the `write` permission is only for administrator.

Comment: Thanks @Bagus for your reply. What access the developers should have? How they generate PR and how can contribute to main repo? How can they Pull updates from main repo?  Any configuration change from my side?